# Installer UI Mode Error

Tags: windows-xp, installer

I wanted to uninstall a software in XP Professional,I encountered "Installer UI Mode Error".
what's the error for?  how it could be fixed?

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: actually i m uninstalling,it s OPNET MODEL LIBRARY V16.0

Answer (score 1):

If your Windows operating system does not have a Java Virtual Machine, this error message may appear when attempting to (un)install a product that does use Java.

If you have uninstalled Java between installing this product and now, you might need to reinstall [Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp) for this uninstaller to work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this error is due to a bug in the installer. It occurs only if your windows user name contains certain characters like ‘!’ or ‘*’ . A simple way is to create another user account with normal user id without any special characters and install from there. Or you can try renaming the existing user id with a normal name without special characters. If you are renaming the userid, it may require a restart for the change to take place.

Or try uninstalling in an administrator account.

Comment: nope,it's not the reason in my opinion;This is a software with software lock and maybe dependencies;